# How to change the within_text value iteratively in Excel's Search function

Tags: search, excel-formula, iteration, substring

I am using the excel search function: `SEARCH(find_text,within_text,[start_num])`

- My find_text is a column of cities in worksheet2, represented by the range A2:A29488
- My within_text is an email address in column C of wooksheet1(the sheet where I am running my formula).
- I am not using the start_num argument.

This is my function: `=SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C62)`

It works and returns the index of the first letter of the city, inside the email address
ex: ...@denver.edu = 5

My problem is that the SEARCH function doesn't just output the index 5, but also outputs an entire column of #VALUE!, which represents the cities that were not in the email address. This means I can not apply my formula to each email address in column C.

So right now I would have to run my formula in a column and find the output values that are numbers.
[Search Formula output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz5BO.png)

Which won't be a problem. The problem is that I can only search through one email address at a time. So I would have to run my function for each row in Column C. Is there a way to have the within_text argument to increase iteratively until my function has run on each row in column C? i.e: `SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C62)..SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C63)....SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C6280)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "entire column of #VALUE!" is a SPILL range, one result for each cell in the `find_text` range.  This is a Excel 365 feature.

You can use other Excel 365 features to reduce this to a single result

```
 =LET(List,IFERROR(SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C62),0),FILTER(List,List>0))
```

This will return a single result only if there is only 1 match.  If there might be > 1 matches, this version will return the first one

```
     =LET(List,IFERROR(SEARCH('Sheet2'!A2:A29488,C62),0),@FILTER(List,List>0))
```

Comment: _It's doing recursion._ Actually, no its not.  It declares a variable `List` to hold the Spill Range.  Then uses that variable (twice) to filter the Spill to a single cell.  Also, [have you seen this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)